# How to test an exit app scenario using detox

Tags: detox

This questions was already raised before, but left without answer in the [issue](https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/226).

What is recommended way to test the current scenario, when on a click of the button there is a `BackHandler.exitApp()` event?

I tried to test like this:

```
await element(by.id('licenseCancelButton')).tap();
await expect(element(by.id('licensePage'))).toBeNotVisible();
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: No activities found. Did you forget to launch the activity by calling getActivity() or startActivitySync or similar?
      at Client.execute (node_modules/detox/src/client/Client.js:92:28)
      at InvocationManager.execute (node_modules/detox/src/invoke.js:11:33)
      at WaitForInteraction.execute (node_modules/detox/src/android/expect.js:128:35)
      at WaitForInteraction.withTimeout (node_modules/detox/src/android/expect.js:161:16)
      at Context.it (e2e/firstTest.spec.js:8:69)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: Could you please explain the use case? I'd like to understand if this is an interesting enough use case to reopen your original issue as an enhancement. When would `exitApp()` be called?

Comment: So in the app I'm working on, we have a license agreement to be accepted by the user. If not, it exists the app.
I'd like this case also to be included in the scenario. So basically when I tap a relevant button the exitApp() happened / the elements from the license agreement view are not visible. Does it makes sense?